# how to view different file extension in different color ib terminal of mac leopard

Tags: macos

I am trying to get colored listing of directories and files as per their extension after ls command. Recently I switched over to mac leopard from Linux. There is no .bashrc file in my home directory, so I created one with the following contents.This is doing only a bit what I want (only directories as colored). I also want to view files with different extension in different colors. What and where to add? thanx in advance :)

```
# Define how Bash prompt looks like:
#
# User @ Host - working dir
#export PS1='\u@\h\w$ '
export PS1='\u@\h\w: '

# Cli Colors
export CLICOLOR=1
# use blue for dir’s
export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad

# Alias
#
#
alias ls='ls -al'
```

Comment: but what should I do if i want to see all my perl programs in a directory with a different color?

Answer (score 5):

The `ls` that comes with OS X is from BSD, and lacks some of the features of its GNU sibling.

To get the result you want, you need to install `coreutils` (assuming you have MacPorts installed, then run `sudo port install coreutils`), which will give you the GNU versions, albeit prefixed by a `g` (i.e. `gls`).

Next, run the command `gdircolors -p > ~/.dir_colors` to generate the file where you will store your colour preferences. It has many common file extensions already present, just add in any missing ones, or change the numbers if you prefer different colours. Or copy an existing one if you already have one from a GNU/Linux installation.

To get your colours to work, first open up `.bash_profile` and add the lines:

```bash
eval `gdircolors ~/.dir_colors`
alias ls="gls --color=auto"
alias ll="gls --color=auto -lh"
alias la="gls --color=auto -a"
```

Which will overrule the BSD versions, and add colour. Then either run `source .bash_profile` or open up a new terminal for the changes to take effect. If you get the error `bash: dircolors: command not found`, then you haven't got `gdircolors` in your path when it is called, so make sure it appears *after* the line that says something like

```bash
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
eval `gdircolors ~/.dir_colors`
```

Finally, I've read in places that this might be better placed in your `.bashrc` file, in which case add the lines to that and add this line at the end of your `.bash_profile`:

```bash
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

No idea if that's necessary or not, I don't have it and haven't had any problems.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. If you have `homebrew` instead MacPorts, you can use the following as a guide to install. 
https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: I have a homebrew installation. None of the above seems to change the default colors I have for directories.

Comment: Are you definitely using `ls`, not `gls`? Try typing `ls --version`, and see what it tells you (GNU's `ls` will tell you the version number, while the BSD `ls` will complain that it's an illegal option).

Also is `gdircolors` working?

Answer (score 2):

ls -Gal (-G does the color)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Snow Leopard is configured not to load ~/.bashrc but instead load ~/.bash_profile. What I did to circumvent this is just create the following ~/.bash_profile:

```
# Load bashrc (settings)
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

For colored ls listing, doesn't ls with colors do what you need? If so, just put this into your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

```
alias ls="ls -G"
```

Hope this helps, xfbs